# Android Crosswalk - Getting the device name

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I compile my Android app using crosswalk, but for some reason I cannot get the device name. I included a  reference to the cordova.js file but nothing happens when I use:

```
alert(device.model)
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I added this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used crosswalk before but in Android if you want to get the model, you'll want to use

```
Build.MODEL;
```

Hopefully that works, if not check out the android documentation on [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Comment: Where in the crosswalk documentation does it say that device.model will work? I know Phone Gap uses device.model but that specific to their platform. Maybe try to utilize something in Navigation. Something like Navigation.platform

Comment: Crosswalk is based on Cordova so most things work, I just am not able to get device info. If I emulate my script in Intel XDK I see the device name, but not when I compile it myself and play my app on my phone, so it must be some configuration or permission settings.

Answer (score 0):

`device.model` does works in **[Crosswalk](http://crosswalk-project.org)** build, you also have to include `cordova.js`.

Here is example code that alerts device.model:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XDK</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="alert(device.model)">Model</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI, thank you but that's what I tried, I mentioned this in my question but for some reason it didn't return anything (did not pop the alert at all so no valid variable).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use a Cordova plugin or any hook with Crosswalk. A simple call to

```
navigator.userAgent
```

This will output something like

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; GT-N7100 Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Mobile Crosswalk/11.40.277.7 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

You can see the device model in the output i.e. GT-N7100